# Zend_Translate with multidimesional arrays

Tags: php, zend-framework, internationalization

I'm using Zend_Translate in my application with the array adapter.

My code looks like this:

```
$english = array(
    'city' => 'City',
    'countryCode' => 'Country Code'
);

$translate = new Zend_Translate(
    array(
        'adapter' => 'array',
        'content' => $english,
        'locale'  => 'en'
    )
);
```

Is there a way to use multimensional arrays, in order to split the translation strings into categories like the below example?

```
 $english = array(
    'country' => array(
        'city' => 'City',
        'countryCode' => 'Country Code'
    )
 );
```

So I could call something like this:

```
$translate->setLocale('en');
echo $translate->_('country/city');
```

Comment: If you need to translate enough text to need such a structure I would suggest you to use a more complex storage system like TMX. It's simple to use, and can be cacheed in the future or edited with translation tools.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. But, there's a way to achieve this without custom adapters?

Comment: I do never use this methods for translation, so I don't know (that's why I've just put a comment). But you could implement it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my mind and now I'm using TMX like AsTeR said.